# How do you display the current timezone with moment-timezone?

Tags: momentjs

While it is clear that you can set a timezone on a `moment` using [`moment-timezone`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/), what is a total mystery is displaying the timezone (long form, not minutes) of a `moment`.

i.e. I would like to do: `moment().tz()` and have it output something like `America/Los_Angeles`

I do not want to set the timezone, I just want to get it to use as `ctz` in a link to [google calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/reference#Parameters).

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution, I've been search for a bit and the only thing I've found is moment().zone() for the short form.

Comment: I didn't find one.  I left off that a while ago and have not revisited yet.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for future users landing on this page: You should be able to access the zone name like so: `m._tz.name` where `m` is a moment object.